# C# Expression partly resolving. Curring?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm writing a generic Entity to Dto Mapper and I have a problem. I want to describe the Mapping programatically.

```
public void ById( Expression<Func<TDto, object>> propertySelector, Expression<Func<TEntity, TDto, bool>> expression ) {
    // Just the Setter what will be mapped
}
```

So in my I call the ById function and pass the required expression. In this case this mapping describes how to fetch a list of entities where the Entity.UserId is equal to the Dto.Id.

```
ById( ( x, y ) => x.UserId.Equals( y.Id ) );
```

The backendservice itself is also generic and generated by the type of "TDto". The backendservice already contains a "Where" function which acceps a function.

```
public List<TEntity> Where<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate) {
    ObjectSet<TEntity> Column = _getGenericColumnByType(); 
    return Column.Where( predicate ).ToList();
}
```

So usually I would call my backend the following way.

```
GenericBackendService<TEntity> Service = // generateMyService;
Guid searchId = // my Guid im searching for
var result = Service.Where( x => x.Id.Equals(searchId));
```

And now there comes my question. Is there a way to resolve the second part of my **( x, y ) => x.UserId.Equals( y.Id )** expression and create a func object like this **x => x.UserId.Equals("123-456-678")**?

```
public Func<TEntity, bool> MagicFunction(Expression<Func<TEntity, TDto, bool>> expression) {
    // 
    // in ->    ( x, y ) => x.UserId.Equals( y.Id )
    //
    // Do the magic
    //
    // out ->     x => x.UserId.Equals("The Id I resolved from y.Id")
    //
    return function;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is... your magic function can't work as you intend.

When you are in your MagicFunction you are working with your expression tree.  y.Id doesn't have a value at this point of time therefore you cant resolve it.  Instead you have to return a function that can resolve y.id when it has a value.  Adding the parameter on your function vastly simplifies things and is effectively the same thing.....

```
public static Func<TEntity, TDto, bool> MagicFunction(Expression<Func<TEntity, TDto, bool>> expression)
    {
        return expression.Compile();
    }
```

Comment: Okay I see. Then I need to overthink my concepts.